# Alter closure variables, vendor JS file automatically runs on load

Tags: javascript, closures

So I'm sure you've seen it before, a vendor JS file that modifies the global space and runs the instant it lands.  I have a vendor JS file, that is generated via a CMS (so I can't just copy it and use it locally), that can't be accessed via CORS (so no .exec here).

This vendor file runs the instant it lands and sets up it's global variables.  One of the functions I need to run depends on a second global variable that may or may not be populated correctly, especially when more than one segment of code modify this variable (the basic problem with global variables).

Anyway here's a rough approximation of what the vendor has given me:

```
// I have no control over this code:
(function (t) {
    var critter = function (options) {
        // Initialize with options
        return options;
    };

    // I have window that's called "t"
    t.pollution = critter({
        doSomething: function (options) {
            // Do some stuff with options
            alert(t.garbage);
        }
    });
})(window);
// End of my "no control" code...
```

The key point is that I have a global `pollution` variable and a function from that called `doSomething()`.  I can't modify that code, but I would like to make the `t` variable inside this function NOT be global.

Per the normal specs of how this should work are as follows:

```
// Sometime later...
(function () {
    // Per the spec, I should modify global variable 'garbage'
    window.garbage = 'wow this is garbage';
    // Lots of potential changes could happen here, not something I would want
    window.pollution.doSomething({});
})();
```

Ideally I would like to send `garbage` in as a parameter, but again I can't mess with that code.  So is it possible to somehow wrap up the `doSomething` function right before I call it and alter it's `t` variable?

The [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```js
// I have no control over this code:
(function (t) {
    var critter = function (options) {
        // Initialize with options
        return options;
    };
        
    // I have window that's called "t"
    t.pollution = critter({
        doSomething: function (options) {
            // Do some stuff with options
            alert(t.garbage);
        }
    });
})(window);
// End of my "no control" code...
        
// Sometime later...
(function () {
    // Per the spec, I should modify global variable 'garbage'
    window.garbage = 'wow this is garbage';
    window.pollution.doSomething({});
        
    // I would like to change the "t" in the closure of doSomething();
})();
```

Comment: What about requesting that file from your server, processing it and sending the result to the client? Would that make sense?

Comment: That's an idea, I might use that as a fallback option.  I might try something around injecting a "setter" onto the t.pollution object.  If it works I'll post it back here.

Comment: There's no way to change the `t` inside `doSomething`. You are out of luck.